# Godot. Как выполнять функцию каждые 10 секунд?

Tags: godot, gdscript

Пишу игру на Godot Engine

Возможно-ли как-то в GDScript выполнять какие-либо действия каждые 10 секунд (или другой промежуток времени)?

Answer (score 0):

Насколько мне извстно, в Godot есть нода для таймера. Оф.документация: https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_timer.html

Пример использования:

```
extends Node

var timer

func _init():
    timer = Timer.new()
    add_child(timer)
    timer.autostart = true
    timer.wait_time = 10
    timer.connect("timeout", self, "_timeout")


func _timeout():
    print("Timed out!")
```